# Find the maximum and minimum value of $|A|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

> For $\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_{51}\in R$, let $A(\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_{51})$ be the average of the complex numbers $e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2},\dots,e^{i\theta_{51}}$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Find the minimum and maximum value of $|A|$.

On applying the triangle inequality for complex numbers, I got $|A|\leq1$. Therefore maximum value of $|A|$ is 1. To find the minimum value, I put all the angles equal to $\pi$ for which each $e^{i\theta_n}$ equals -1. On further calculation, I got, $|A|$=1. Therefore the minimum value is also one.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's be a bit more general: Let $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0, 1\}$ and $\theta_1,...,\theta_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and let
$$A:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \exp(i \theta_k)$$
You've already shown that
$$|A| \leqslant 1$$
with the triangle inequality. We can easily show an example for $|A|=1$ with $\theta_i=0$ for all $i=1,...,n$. It's also clear that $|A| \geqslant 0$ from the properties of the absolute value, so we just need to prove that $|A|=0$ is possible. Let
$$\omega_k=\exp\left(\frac{2ki \pi}{n}\right)$$
I claim that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \omega_k = 0$$
Can you prove it?

Comment: Why have you written $\omega_k=\exp(\frac{2ki\pi}{n})$?

Comment: @MrAP Because $\omega_k$ is the $n$-th root of the unity, i.e. $\omega_1^n=...=\omega_n^n=1$. It's quite easy to see that for even $n$ their sum is $0$, and it can be proven that it's $0$ for odd $n$ ass well.

Comment: I cannot see how "It's quite easy to see that $\dots$ their sum is $0$". Can you please explain that? I only know that the sum of the $n$ $n$-th roots of unity is equal to $0$.

Comment: @MrAP Aren't my omegas the n-th roots of unity?

Comment: Yes. But I do not understand how "It's quite easy to see that for even $n$ their sum is $0$". Also I would like to know why have you considered even and odd $n$ separately.

Comment: @MrAP The proof goes the same way for both odd and even $n$. It's easy to see for me that it's true for even $n$ if I imagine them as points on the unit circle. Of course, it's not something rigorous, but a good starting point. So you don't need to care about that part at all :)

Comment: But why have you considered even and odd $n$ separately?

Comment: Can't we directly use the result that the sum of the $n$ $n$th roots of unity is $0$?

Comment: @MrAP As I told you it before, I considered them separately because it was easier to see the even case geometrically. I didn't know that you know that result, so I was trying to convince you that it's true, and leave the proof for you.

Comment: @MrAP Yes, you can, and you should, as I pointed out it in my answer originally.

Comment: Oh. So the maximum value is $1$ and the minimum value is $0$. Right?

Comment: @MrAP exactly. ${}$